# Mocking states and props on tests

Tags: reactjs, testing

I have a code in which I created NavbarMock which wraps Navbar component (which is supposed to be tested) in needed providers. To pass its needed props to it I created new states (named: language/search). I just want be able to render component but I cannot do it unless I pass these props. Can I mock them somehow so there will be no need to actually use them?

```
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { messages } from "../../App/App.const";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import {
  DarkModeContext,
  DarkModeContextProvider,
} from "../../contexts/DarkModeContext";


describe("testing navbar component", () => {
  function NavbarMock() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");
    return (
      <IntlProvider
        messages={messages[language as keyof typeof messages]}
        locale={language}
        defaultLocale="en"
      >
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar
            setLanguage={setLanguage}
            language={language}
            setSearch={setSearch}
            search={search}
          />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }

  test("renders logo correctly", () => {
    render(<NavbarMock />);
    const logo = screen.getByText(/Todoly/i);
    expect(logo).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry I didn't read the question properly on the first go.

Your test could look something along these lines, so you don't have to create a whole wrapper but only pass the props directly to your component from the render function and you can also add providers argument.

I hope it helps!

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("renders logo correctly", async () => {

   const { findByText } = render(<Navbar prop1="123" prop2="234 />, {
    // Providers here can be some wrappers like yours but more generic
    wrapper: Providers,
   });

   expect(await findByText("Some-text")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```